# Theory of Special Relativity Paradox. How to solve it?

Tags: special-relativity

Imagine two stars A & B 10ly apart with no relative motion between each other. At the half distance, there's a platform. These stars emit two photons from each, towards the platform simultaneously
Two spaceships are coming from opposite directions and going to pass by the platform. By coincidence, these two photons and the two spaceships pass by the platform at the same moment. Let's call this event, the event of coincidence.

Now imagine a second observer M. This observer is on the way towards the space station. But he reaches there before the spaceships. Then after reaching there, he changes his direction towards the star A.
My drawing is from space station's frame of reference. Even if we watch it from the M's frame of reference after he changes his direction, the coincidence has to happen.

After he changes the direction, the distance between stars A & B are contracted. Space ships and photons are still on their way.

In the observer M's new frame of reference, the sun A is closing and sun B is moving away. That means the photon from A and the space ship X has to run a lot of distance to catch up with the space station. Meanwhile, the photon from B and spaceship Y which were already on their way are rapidly closing in with the space station.
But the rapidly closing spaceship Y and Photon B  somehow have to be DELAYED at the middle of their journey in an attempt to prevent the collapse of coincidence.
How do you explain this "midway delay" of photons from B?[image]

Comment: Your last paragraph does not make much sense to me. Just because the speeds relative to the space station change, does not mean their relative speeds to the platform change. The whole length A to B becomes shorter, that does not influence the event of coincidence. You'll have to elaborate on that point.

Comment: Try figuring out the times at which the photons were emitted in M's new frame.

Comment: What is the need of the "old" frame of M, that is its motion perpendicular to the line AB  ??? Is it a trick to confuse us ??? Why don't you say that M is an observer moving towards A and being  at space station before the coincidence ???

Comment: OK. You have created a thought experiment and you have name it arbitrarily  "a paradox". I wonder if all these "by words defined variables", for example : (1) "... distance between stars A & B are contracted..." , (2) "... the sun A is closing and sun B is moving away..." , (3) "...has to run a lot of distance to catch up ..." , (4) "...on their way are rapidly closing..." ,  (5) "..."midway delay"..." , (6) "...     ...", etc  have any relation with physics. A last question  : Do you have any idea about the Lorentz transformation in which you try to find "paradoxes" and "contradictions" ???

Answer (score 0):

Observer accelerates, so now-moments at distance change according to the observer.

Let's view the star and the photon at the left as a clock. The photon and the star at the right is another clock.

These two clocks behave opposite ways: One runs fast forward, while the other one runs slowly.

So, doesn't that solve the problem?

Comment: I apologize for this comment, but the clocks in Special Relativity are not video players with fast forwards and fast backwards movements.

Comment: I upvoted the comment of @Frobenius, but I want  to make clear that the upvote does not apply to the apology.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there can be no paradoxes.  Draw the spacetime diagram with all the worldlines.  If you change coordinates, the worldlines are still what they are, just labeled differently.  The labels you choose to put on things can't change their actual properties (such as whether multiple lines cross at a single point, etc.)

But if something's still bothering you, and you want to resolve it, start by calculating the times at which the photons are emitted in $M$'s new frame.

Then, at each of these times, figure out where the spaceships and the stars are according to $M$'s new frame.  (I prefer to do this by first working in $M$'s original frame, writing down the equations for his line of simultaneity and, say, the worldline of Spaceship A, solving for the intersection point, and then Lorentz transforming to $M$'s new frame.  There are, of course, other ways to do it that you might prefer.)

This will let you write down a timeline of everything that's happening in  $M$'s new frame, and all will be clear.

So you can check your work,  here's how that calculation works out if we assume the spaceships have speed 1/2 and $M$ travels leftward at speed 4/5.  I also assume that in the original frame, the photons are emitted at locations -2 and 2, when the spaceships are at locations -1 and 1.  Then in the new frame:

> Time -2.67:  
>
> Photon A emitted from star A at location -3.33
> Spaceship A is at location -2.9 (traveling rightward at speed .93)
> Spaceship B is at location -.33 (traveling rightward at speed .5)
> Star B is at location -.933 (traveling rightward at speed .8)

> Time +2.67:
>   
>
> Star A is at location 3.33 (traveling rightward at speed .8)
>
> Photon A is at location 2
>
> Spaceship A is at location 2.05
>
> Spaceship B is at location 2.33
>
> Photon B is emitted from star B at location 3.33

> Time +3.3:
>
> Photon A, Spaceship A, Spaceship B, and Photon B all meet up at location 2.67.